# add string variable to integer and get result in string format

Tags: vb.net

I have a string variable like this:

```
Dim Mrnnoincriment As String
Dim s As String() = dr1(0).ToString().Split(New Char() { "_"c})
Mrnnoincriment = s(0) + 1
Dim hhid As String = s(0)
Dim finalmrno As String = hhid & "" & Mrnnoincriment
```

**my `dr1(0)` value is `"L1"`** I want to add `1`.
My expected output is `"L2"`

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Integer.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) function to parse the string to an integer and then add 1 to it:

```
Mrnnoincriment = (Integer.Parse(s(0)) + 1).ToString("00");
```

Also note the string format in `ToString()`. It will pad the result with a leading zero.

Working example : at [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pChJQk).

Comment: sir i have a doubt ,can i ask